# Change a key values based on a different value

Tags: yaml, yq

I have the following YAML file :

```
affinityCookieTtlSec: 0
backends:
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 0.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/production/regions/us/instanceGroups/prod-instance-service-green
  maxRatePerInstance: 900.0
  maxUtilization: 0.8
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 1.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/production/regions/us/instanceGroups/prod-instance-service-blue
  maxRatePerInstance: 900.0
  maxUtilization: 0.8
```

Using `yq`, I would like to change the `capacityScaler` value based on `group` value, for example:
If `group` is equal to `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/production/regions/us/instanceGroups/prod-instance-service-green`, change the capacityScaler in the same list to `0.5`.
So the output should be:

```
affinityCookieTtlSec: 0
backends:
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 0.5
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/production/regions/us/instanceGroups/prod-instance-service-green
  maxRatePerInstance: 900.0
  maxUtilization: 0.8
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 1.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/production/regions/us/instanceGroups/prod-instance-service-blue
  maxRatePerInstance: 900.0
  maxUtilization: 0.8
```

So far, I figured I can list the lists by `yq e '.backends[0]` or `yq e '.backends[1]`, but I'm not able to select the correct list by the `group` value.

Comment: There's more than one tool named `yq`. Be sure you're specifying which one -- I can tell from the sample command lines given that you're talking about the one that isn't just a wrapper in front of jq, but you might get answers aimed at the other one as-is. (Personally, I'm only qualified to answer for the one that _is_ a `jq` wrapper).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the syntax you've shown in the question, I would assume you are using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq).

Its DSL is almost similar to that of `jq`, so you can use `select` operator for choosing the right record and use the `|=` to update the desired value

```
yq e '(.backends[] | select(.group == "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/production/regions/us/instanceGroups/prod-instance-service-green").capacityScaler) |= 0.5' yaml
```